# why do i get Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a bottomModalSheet to pop up when I tap on an IconButton , but I keep on getting 'undefined name 'context' when I run my code

```
 Widget mealSize() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      const Text(
        " size",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
        ),
        iconSize: 20,
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return buildSheet();
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Widget buildSheet() => Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: const [Icon(Icons.add_circle), Text("Add Size variant")],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your context is missing here:

```dart
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return buildSheet();
            },
          );
```

It's not defined as the error says.

Comment: im totally new at flutter , how do i go about defining the context ?

Comment: A stateful or stateless widget provides the contex. The context depends on where you call your widget. Lookup here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at where you're defining mealsize(). There's no context being passed in, so where is the showModalBottomSheet going to get the context from? You have to pass one in to mealsize()

```
Widget mealsize({required BuildContext context}){
  // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you this seemed to have solved the problem for me